# c++ class member accessed via getter yields garbage, direct access ok but std::cout interferes?

Tags: c++, pointers, getter, cout

I'm new to c++ and tried to get familiar with the language by implementing a LinkedList.

```
class ListElement {
public:
    int val;
    ListElement *next;

    ListElement(int v, ListElement *n) {val = v; next = n;};
};
```

`ListElement` contains an int value `val` and a pointer to the next list element (`nullptr` if there is no next element) and a constructor.

```
class MyLinkedList {
public:
    ListElement *head;

    MyLinkedList() {head = nullptr;};

    ListElement* getHead(void){
        return head;
    };

    void append(int i) {
        head = &ListElement(i, head);
    };
};
```

`MyLinkedList` contains a pointer to the first element of the list named `head` as well as some methods working on the list. Encountering some bugs in those methods I tried to track down their cause. (I'm aware that a getter for a public class member makes no sense at all, originally `head` was private.) Doing so I observed the following behaviour I can't explain:

```
int main() {
    MyLinkedList l;
    l.append(1);

    int x = l.head->val;
    cout << "head: " << x << "\n";
    int y = l.getHead()->val;
    cout << "getHead(): " << y << "\n";
    int z = l.head->val;
    cout << "head: " << z << "\n";

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Running this code (add `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;` for a working example) prints

```
head: 1
getHead(): 18085840
head: -858993460
```

so the first direct access of `head` works just as expected, yielding `1` as value of the first list element, but using the getter returns garbage. If `head` is then accessed directly again, it also yields garbage, which made me think "Hm, seems like using getHead() somehow garbles the ListMember object", just to discover that

```
int x = l.head->val;
cout << "head: " << x << "\n";
int z = l.head->val;
cout << "head: " << z << "\n";
```

prints

```
head: 1
head: -858993460
```

without even touching the getter. So is simply accessing `l.head` in any way enough to garble it?

No, as

```
int x = l.head->val;
int z = l.head->val;
cout << "head: " << x << "\n";
cout << "head: " << z << "\n";
```

returns (as intended) `head: 1` two times. So using `cout` in between changes my objects or their pointers? And what's wrong with `getHead()` as all it does is just `return head;`?

---

So I'm pretty lost here and couldn't find any directly related questions. ([This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924271/accessing-elements-of-a-list-via-a-getter-versus-direct-access-to-the-class-memb) has a promising title but doesn't use pointers). Am I totally failing to use pointers in a correct way? Or is some automatic object deletion going on behind the scenes? Or is this just how magiC++ works?

Comment: `head = &ListElement(i, head);` - that is not how you allocate a new `ListElement`. Go read about `new` (and then for most cases, try to avoid needing it).

Comment: for good measure, you might also want to know about [smart pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)

Comment: @jaggedSpire Right, my bad - too late to think straight I guess :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ you must manage your own memory.  The statement

```
ListElement(i, head);
```

Creates an instance of ListElement locally scoped the MyLinkedList::append().  Thus once that function exits the variable no longer exists and the pointer is now pointing at invalid memory.

The reason your first print statement is giving you a seemingly correct answer is a bit of a red herring.  In all cases you are accessing free-ed memory which has undefined behavior.  In the first case that memory just happens to have the value that you previously set.

You have to allocate your own memory in append and clean it up when you are done with it.  Once you have mastered "new" be sure to look up how to iterate through a data structure and delete each element.  With your linked listed implementation this should be fairly trivial.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
void append(int i) {
    head = &ListElement(i, head);
};
```

`ListElement(i, head)` creates a temporary, nameless `ListElement` and assigns a pointer to it to `head`. Then, because the `ListElement` itself wasn't assigned to anything, the `ListElement` [goes out of scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) and is destroyed. This leaves head pointing to invalid memory.

Head could be written to use dynamic memory to extent the life of the `ListElement`

```
void append(int i) {
    head = new ListElement(i, head);
};
```

but now someone has to pick up the responsibility of ensuring that the `ListElement` is deleted when no longer required.

For example:

```
void remove(int i) {
    // find list element i and previous element. Special handling required for first element
    prev.next = element.next;
    delete element;
};
```

Careful use of [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [std::move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) can get automate the memory management and eliminate the need for `delete`.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
void append(int i) {
    head = &ListElement(i, head);
};
```

to

```
void append(int i) {
    head = new ListElement(i, head);
};
```

The first, if it compiles, is taking the address of a temporary stack allocated object. Hence `head` will "point at garbage" after it's destruction.